# React Context - How to structure user posts

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am implementing an Instagram clone. In my current app, I have two contexts:

1. UsersContext
2. PostsContext

In the users context, I store all the users data, and in the other one, I store the posts data (images, dimensions, description, totalLikes, totalComments, and location).

As you can see, I am not storing nothing about the post owner... neither his id, nor his avatar or username... literally there is no data about users in the PostsContext.

In my card component, I am consuming both contexts, in order to synchronize all the UI with the most up-to-date data which is relative to users and posts.

My question is: should I include the posts owners' data inside the PostsContext? Is there any kind of pattern or something? This is my first time using React Context API, I am a little lost. Is the only purpose of contexts to make things globally and synchronize all routes?

Any example?

Comment: The most straight-forward way to do this is to have an ID for each post owner. Then you can extract their data from the `UsersContext` by these IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally I would order the providers this way.

```
<UserContextProvider>
  ...
  <PostContextProvider uid={uid}>
    ...
  </PostContextProvider>
</UserContextProvider>
```

Where I make a provider function that will look like

```
export function PostContextProvider({uid, children}) {
  const posts = getPosts(uid);
  return (
    <PostContext.Provider values={{posts}}>
      {children}
    </PostContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

then access the posts.